# Appendix title showing up after the image contents

Tags: appendices

The appendix title does not come in the beginning, rather the content is being shown at first. The first appendix where there is only text, shows up with Appendix at top and then text follows it, however, for the case where there is image in appendix, first the image shows up then, the title for the appendix shows up.I want the appendix title come at first.

and also the MWE is :

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\title{\textbf{Laser Pointer Based Human-Computer-Interaction using Computer-Vision}}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{mysize}{\fontsize{8}{9.6}\selectfont}
\captionsetup{font=mysize}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
    \apptocmd{\appendices}{\let\LaTeXStandardTheSection\thesection
    \apptocmd{\figure}{\let\thesection\LaTeXStandardTheSection}{}{}
\apptocmd{\thesection}{:}{}{}}{}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}
\section{Raspberry Pi and Camera Board}
    Raspberry Pi is a single-board computer with processor
\section{Projected Screen After Exposure Correction}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{projectorwithout.png}
\caption{Projected Screen After Exposure Correction}
\label{}
\end{figure}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why so many packages in MWE? I don't own most of them, thus resulting difficult to analize. Suggestion: load `hyperref` last, that will save some errors.

Comment: it's more convenient for other participants in this forum if you can insert the example code directly in the question.  that also protects it from code rot when other sites decide a posting is no longer current.

Comment: I posted so many packages in MWE so that, if there is some overrides between packages, that might have resulted in such output, you guys would help me find out?

Comment: Yes, but it's taking a while. :)  
Maybe this isn't your case, but it seems difficult to me that one document requires that many packages. For some features required once I suggest doing the trick manually, instead leaving it to a package. But, I repeat, maybe this isn't your case.

Comment: That is quite smart of you, but I am new to this and I used whatever, I was suggested to use by people here, via answers and stuff. Btw my document is a project report, longer than 50 pages with contents full of flowcharts and images and gantt charts, so :D the packages.

Comment: @tilaprimera the point of a _minimal_ example is that you should just include the minimum required to demonstrate the problem. You don't have to guess if the packages interact, simply delete everything that you can delete, checking at each stage that the example demonstrates your problem. then post the smallest document that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to define an environment basically compatible to `figure` making it possible to give captions and labels and hence being able to reference the pictures in the appendix.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\title{\textbf{Laser Pointer Based Human-Computer-Interaction using Computer-Vision}}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{mysize}{\fontsize{8}{9.6}\selectfont}
\captionsetup{font=mysize}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
    \apptocmd{\appendices}{\let\LaTeXStandardTheSection\thesection
    \apptocmd{\figure}{\let\thesection\LaTeXStandardTheSection}{}{}
\apptocmd{\thesection}{:}{}{}}{}{}

\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{appendixfig}{}{
   \par\medskip\noindent
   \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
   \def\@captype{figure}
   \centering
}
{
\end{minipage}
\par\bigskip
}
\makeatother 
\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}
\section{Raspberry Pi and Camera Board}
    Raspberry Pi is a single-board computer with processor
\section{Projected Screen After Exposure Correction}
\begin{appendixfig}
\includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Projected Screen After Exposure Correction}
\label{}
\end{appendixfig}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

There are some oddities in your code; you are loading packages twice, and do you really need to use `utf8x`? It can do some crazy stuff when you don't expect it.

Comment: that is a mistake in copy paste, ignore that.

Comment: I need the figure wrapper for the captions. Melons!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution, as well as some minor improvements to the preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\title{\textbf{Laser Pointer Based Human-Computer-Interaction using Computer-Vision}}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[top=3.5cm, bottom=2cm, left=3.5cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{mysize}{\fontsize{8}{9.6}\selectfont}
\captionsetup{font=mysize}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\text{Figure} }
\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{\text{Table} }
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{APPENDIX}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}
\renewcommand\cftsecleader{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\apptocmd{\appendices}{\let\LaTeXStandardTheSection\thesection
\apptocmd{\figure}{\let\thesection\LaTeXStandardTheSection}{}{}
\apptocmd{\thesection}{:}{}{}}{}{}
\hypersetup{
    hidelinks = true
}
    \apptocmd{\appendices}{\let\LaTeXStandardTheSection\thesection
    \apptocmd{\figure}{\let\thesection\LaTeXStandardTheSection}{}{}
    \apptocmd{\thesection}{:}{}{}}{}{}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{appendices}
    \section{Raspberry Pi and Camera Board}
        Raspberry Pi is a single-board computer with processor
    \section{Projected Screen After Exposure Correction}
    \begin{center}
        \label{}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.30]{projectorwithout.png}
        {Projected Screen After Exposure Correction}
    \end{center}
    \end{appendices}
    \end{document}
```

Sometimes `float`s are not so intuitive to handle, sometimes it's better to avoid them. This is one of these cases, and `\includegraphics` alone places always the image where it's written.